# How to remove button background color

Tags: android, button

I searched a lot but I didn't find how to remove the background color from the button which is appearing on the right and left side of button. Can anybody help?

My screen looks like [image: screenshot]

No matter what I try I am not able to remove the black portion.

Code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_base"
                android:text="@string/base" 
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
           <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_care"
                android:text="@string/care"
                android:layout_margin="2dp" 
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_daily_prize"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/daily_prize" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_winner"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/winner" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

@Drawable/selector_button

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"> </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/change"></item>


</selector>
```

[image] this is the image used with name change.9.png

Comment: Maybe you should also add the drawables that you used for your buttons.

Comment: Is selector_button drawable a 9patch?

Comment: Drawable/selector_button is just a back image which u r seeing in image. Dim is 96*26. yes, that is 9patch

Comment: plzzzzz is longer than "please", damn it to hell and back. do not use LONGER ABBREVIATION in place of regular english!.

Comment: I agree the Problem iS propably to be found in your image

Comment: Giving -1 is easy but answer... I still didn't got

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your scenario i can surely say that either you are not using a 9-patch image (an image with extension like .9.png ) or the 1 pixel borders of 9-patch at left and top are not drawn in correct manner. thats why the edges and the side border shade get expanded with the button with long width. either you should show what 9-patch button background you have used or try some correct 9-patch and check results for that.

Comment: edited my question with requirement. And also  I rechecked it with draw9patch.bat

Comment: Ok, My image was not 9 patch one. So I accept your answer. Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use some other control element like `TextView` instead of buttons? I just saw that `TextView` has `onClickListner` and so you can use it as sort-of button, though I have not done it; button is meant to aid you defining your layout, but as this seems to only be a problem for you, just do not use it).

By the way I seriously recommend you to use [android styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), as you copy-paste a lot of attributes. If you use Eclipse for development, open your layout xml, select the item you want to extract the style of, press `ctrl + 1` and then select extract style. That way you should avoid copy-pasting all these style attributes.

Comment: Yes that can be done, but I need to stick to default functionality. That is using button where button are required. But thanks for adding this to my knowledge.

Comment: Actually, now I remember I have done what you want in several projects, never had your issue. Can you please really give the code of `@drawable/selector_button`

Comment: <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed"> </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/focused"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/change"></item>
    

</selector>

Comment: Ok wrong request. I do not need the selector, I need the shapes (i.e. `@drawable/pressed` and so on). Also you can edit your question adding this information, because it is important for everybody that want to help you).

Comment: I added the shape also. just the default one

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the android:textColor attribute. These can be misleading and sometimes alter the colour of more than just the text. If the text is supposed to be black then you don't need it.

Comment: That is the color for text and no relation with background. Any ways I tried it, and same result is there, except from my text color, that goes default one.